# What does "Difference in AUROC significantly shifted from zero at the 0.05 level as compared to that of a random forest." mean?

Tags: machine-learning

As a starter, I am coming from an electronical engineering background with heavy signal processing focus.
Due to our new funding in the lab, I have just started to read some papers regarding biomedical data analysis and I would like to learn the general lingo that is used in the tables or at least a  guideline paper (or a book).

As an example, I know what AUROC is but I did not understand what is meant by the sentence "*" below the Table 2. In addition, do the values in parenthesis on the right side of cell values indicate p-value or something else?

[image]

Sorry for the newbie questions.

EDIT: Link for the original paper  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4101570/

Comment: Could you please provide a link or reference to the source of that table? There might be important details in the rest of the article. It’s best to do that by editing the question, as comments on this site are easy to overlook and can get deleted.

Comment: I've added the link for the original paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this paper compares the performance of different machine learning methods. The note says they conducted 100 simulations (bootstrap runs) for each row and calculated the mean and the standard deviation (in the parentheses) across the simulations.

They add "*" to the methods whose performance (measured by the AUROC score) is significantly different from its Random forest counterpart.  This is what they mean by "difference in the AUROC shifted from zero", i.e. the difference is away from zero, and the "0.05 level" indicates that they chose 95% as the significance level.